# about SAXparseException: content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml

I am using glassfish server and the following error keeps coming:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:304)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:480)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:213)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationArchivist.openArchive(ApplicationArchivist.java:813)
        at com.sun.enterprise.instance.WebModulesManager.getDescriptor(WebModulesManager.java:395)
        ... 65 more
```

Comment: Please provide the `<?xml...` declaration and a hex dump of the first few lines of the deployment descriptor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

Answer (score 4):

Check this link

http://mark.koli.ch/2009/02/resolving-orgxmlsaxsaxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog.html

In short, some XML file contains the three-byte pattern (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF) at the front (right before `<?xml ...?>`), which is the UTF-8 byte order mark. The java's default XML parser can't handle this case.

The quick and dirty solution is to remove the white space at the front of the XML file:

```
String xml = "<?xml ...";
xml = xml.replaceFirst("^([\\W]+)<","<");
```

note that the String.trim() dost not enough, since it only trim the limited whitespace characters.

Comment: Nice catch, I just got burned by the UTF8 Bom on a series of files.

Comment: A better solution is to use the `BOMInputStream` provided by the Spring framework.

Comment: Great! Solved it.