# Fatal Error :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml

I'm using Java and i'm trying to get XML document from some http link. Code I'm using is:

```
URL url = new URL(link);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
Document doc = null;

CountInputStream in = new CountInputStream(url.openStream());
doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);
```

Don't pay attention at `CountInputStream`, it's some special class acting like regular input stream.

Using the code above, I sometimes got error `Fatal Error :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog`. I assume that is has something to do with bad format of xml, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java parsing XML document gives "Content not allowed in prolog." error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599919/java-parsing-xml-document-gives-content-not-allowed-in-prolog-error)

Comment: Well as i understood thread you're referring to is about reading xml from disk. In my case i don't have xml on the disk, i just have some string (link) and i got error before i got xml file...

Comment: Can you give the URL in question? The most likely cause of this is a malformed response, so a look at that would be valuable.

Comment: It does not matter where XML file originates from, errors are still the same.

"Content not allowed in prolog" refers to the fact that something else but not <?xml ...> opening tag was found at the beginning of the file/stream. If it contains extra spaces just trim them, but generally this sort of error is not (programmatically) recoverable.

Comment: After reading you comments i have manually checked the response of http page and it really had badly formatted xml... sorry for bothering you, i never had problems like that before... :\

Comment: The fault is in the resource you are reading, which you have not provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*I'm turning my comment to an answer, so it can be accepted and this question no longer remains unanswered.*

The most likely cause of this is a malformed response, which includes characters before the initial `<?xml …>`. So please have a look at the document as transferred over HTTP, and fix this on the server side.

Comment: These weird characters at starting of file are BOM (byte order mark), ideally BOM should not be present with utf-8 encoding as java fails to parse such exception and gives above error

Answer (score 9):

There are certainly some weird characters (e.g. [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) or some whitespace before the XML preamble (`<?xml ...?>`)?

Comment: In my case I had wrongly added comments in xml using java style comments. e.g. Instead of using  <!-- -->  I had used  /*     */  removing that fixed the same for me

Answer (score 3):

I wanted YAML for the log4j2 configuration file because it doffs XML's visual clutter, but had the same error as Guest96.  I scoured the web for a solution to the above, investigating a Utf-8 BOM or other content in the YAML header area; no joy.  Of course, the answer is usually simple.

Somewhere, I had fully missed it that using YAML with log4j2 required the *jackson* libraries, per https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/log4j2-configuration-detailed-guide/.  Adding the *jackson* reference to my (Gradle) configuration fixed the problem:

```
// Gain support for log4j2.
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.1'
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.1'

// Gain support for YAML with log4j2.
// https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/log4j2-configuration-detailed-guide/
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.10.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0'
```

With that, the dreaded **Fatal Error :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog** error went away.

Answer (score 1):

The real solution that I found for this issue was by *disabling any XML Format post processors*.  I have added a post processor called "`jp@gc - XML Format Post Processor`" and started noticing the error "`Fatal Error :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog`"

**By disabling** the post processor had stopped throwing those errors.

Answer (score 0):

Someone should mark Johannes Weiß's comment as the answer to this question. That is exactly why xml documents can't just be loaded in a DOM Document class.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0):

It could be *not supported file encoding*. Change it to UTF-8 for example.

I've done this using [Sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289157/set-encoding-of-file-to-utf8-with-bom-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you forgot adding correct headers to your get request (ask the REST API developer or you specific API description):

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.header("Accept", "application/xml")
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
```

or

```
connection.header("Accept", "application/xml;version=1")
```