# Set Encoding of File to UTF8 With BOM in Sublime Text 3

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, byte-order-mark

When I open a file in Sublime Text 3, at the bottom I have an option to set the Character Encoding as shown in the screenshot.

[image: setting encoding]

There is the option to set it to **UTF-8** , which after doing some research means UTF-8 Without BOM, but I want to set it to **UTF-8 With BOM** like shown below:

[image: UTF-8 with BOM]

How can I do this from within ST3?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I can't set "UTF-8 with BOM" in the corner button either, but I can change it from the menu bar.

"File"->"Save with encoding"->"UTF-8 with BOM"

Answer (score 180):

Into **Preferences > Settings - Users** 
File : Preferences.sublime-settings

Write this :

> "show_encoding" : true,

It's explain on the release note date 17 December 2013. Build 3059.
[Official site Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)

Comment: in all fairness, before i downvote this was it correct at some point?  In the current release `show_encoding` does not offer a "with BOM" option and therefore does not answer the question.

Comment: Did I misunderstanding here? This doesn't answer the question at all.....

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but I have to admit that it helped me figure out a problem I was having with my code being interpreted as Chinese characters

Comment: does not answer the question and does not work in ST3

Answer (score 4):

**Into the Preferences > Setting - Default**

You will have the next by default:

```
// Display file encoding in the status bar
    "show_encoding": false
```

You could change it or like cdesmetz said set your user settings.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Sublime Text set `'UTF8 without BOM'`, but that wasn't specified.

The only specicified things is `'UTF8 with BOM'`.

Hope this help :)