# strange words appear when extract arabic text from pdf (PdfToText)

Tags: php, pdftotext

I have a problem when extract arabic text from pdf.
I use [PdfToText](https://github.com/christian-vigh-phpclasses/PdfToText) library
The text appears in this figure (΋ΎϬϧϟ΍υϔΣϟ΍ΦϳέΎΗ ΏϟΎρϟ΍ϡϳΩϘΗΝΫϭϣϧ ΩϳϘϟ΍ϡϗέ) 
How can i solve it ? i tried

```html
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
```

but this did not solve my problem

Comment: I'm unsure but it could be an encoding issue - have you tested it with plain English PDF?

Comment: yes i tested it in english pdf and it works well 
but in arabic pdf didn't work

Comment: I've never used it and unsure if it's open source to download once registered but perhaps this could help? http://arabicpdf.com/PdfDebugger/

Answer (score 0):

English letters are part of basic ASCII char set so the output is usually without any problems however any other languages using various accents or even different letters, ie. Arabic, Azbuka, Greek, etc. uses letters out of the basic set.

Make sure all three sources are using same encoding:

1. all the PHP scripts generating the output
2. the HTML encoding meta tag
3. the output file as well

ad 1
Check your editor how it saves the PHP scripts to the file system. The way how to set it up differs from each editor

ad 2
Use HTML meta tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

ad 3
define the encoding to use `UTF-8` for example: `pdftotext -enc UTF-8 your.pdf`. According to the documentation the PdfToText class generates UTF8-encoded text.

Comment: how i can define the encoding to use utf-8 ?

Comment: I have mentioned 3 places where it should be set. Which one is your question related to?

Comment: The official documentation of PdfToText says that its class generates UTF8-encoded text.

Comment: So I would focus on First item and made sure your IDE is saving PHP scripts in UTF-8. What is your php script editor? Is it saving your files in proper encoding?

Comment: and the encoding?

Comment: Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: how i can now the encoding?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289157/set-encoding-of-file-to-utf8-with-bom-in-sublime-text-3

Comment: the same problem

Comment: Are you sure  PdfToText  library supports Arabic alphabet?

Comment: Do you have something else?