# Can children nodes' tags be same as root node?

Tags: java, xml

I'm stuck on an assignment where I have to read data from an XML response of an API. The root node and all the children nodes have the same tag.
Eg.

```
<a //some attributes>
      <a>
        <element1>value1</element1>
        <element2>value2<element2>
      </a>
      <a>
        <element1>value3</element1>
        <element2>value4<element2>
      </a>
</a>
```

The java code is as follows:
.
.

```
if (format == "xml") {
    try {

    URL url = new URL("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/" + cc + "/indicator/" + ic + "?scale=y&format=" + format + "&date=" + start + ":" + end);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    String response1 = response.toString();

    response1 = response1.substring(1); //resolving problem in API response. referred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577420/fatal-error-11-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog for error
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response1)));


    NodeList Node = doc.getElementsByTagName("wb:data");

    if (Node.getLength() > 0) {
        Element ele = (Element)Node.item(0);
        NodeList Node2=(NodeList) doc.getChildNodes();
        boolean flag=false;
        String spage_total=ele.getAttribute("pages");

        int page_total=Integer.parseInt(spage_total);
        String scount=ele.getAttribute("per_page");

        int count=Integer.parseInt(scount);
        String stotal=ele.getAttribute("total");

        int total=Integer.parseInt(stotal);
        if (total < count) count = total;
        if(Node2.getLength()>0){
        Element ele2 = (Element)Node2.item(0);
        String svalue=ele2.getElementsByTagName("wb:date").toString();
        System.out.println(svalue);//this is where it says com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@6b1274d2
    }}
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

}

.
.

My question is, is it possible to read data from such an XML?

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly valid XML. It's not terribly *helpful* in terms of readability, but it's fine.

Comment: I can't seem to access the child nodes' elements. I always get this instead-DeepNodeListImpl@c8e4bb0(the value after @ is variable).

Comment: Add some Java source to the question.

Comment: With respect to `if (format == "xml")` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832

Comment: I'll change that. Thanks

Comment: Got what was supposed to be done. I was using the statement wrong. Thankyou for your responses.