# Exception parsing Vector Asset in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable, androidsvg

I am getting issue while I try to generate Vector Asset from a SVG file contains in my local folder as per the new Android Studio version 1.4 support feature for Vector Drawables. I have attached the screenshot of the error I am getting as follows

[image]

I am really confused and don't know how to proceed since Vector Drawable(SVG) support is new to me in Android. Any kind of help would be useful for me. Thanks in advance.

**Note:** The default **Material Icon** are working great but I am facing problem only while I try to import from **Local SVG file**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599919/java-parsing-xml-document-gives-content-not-allowed-in-prolog-error      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030903/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-when-parsing-perfectly-valid-xml-on-gae

Answer (score 1):

As I noticed and imported the svg to to the vectors , svg having path only is easily convertible to vector drawables. There is certain limitation to the vector drawables as they only use the path (as denoted by d in svg) to draw a shape.