# JAXB : .UnmarshalException - with linked exception: [javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException

Tags: java, xml, exception, jaxb

Can anyone help me to figure out the root cause for this issue.

**XML:**

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="https://*******/odata/**/">
```

**Code :**

```
      jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Entry.class);
      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

      XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();

      xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
      XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(metaData));

      Entry entry = (Entry) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
```

**Class:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "entry")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {
```

**Exception:**

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Make sure your XML doesn't have [a BOM at the start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599919/java-parsing-xml-document-gives-content-not-allowed-in-prolog-error). Your XML is also missing a closing root tag.

Comment: checked the xml file and no junk characters. @approxiblue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your string below :

```
 byte[] metaBytes = metaData.getBytes();
 String input = new String(metaBytes, "UTF-8");
```

Use SAX Parser

```
      SAXParserFactory parserFactory;
      parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
      parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
      XMLReader reader = parserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
      Source er = new SAXSource(reader, new InputSource(new StringReader(input)));
```