# Content is not allowed in prolog when calling a soap webservice

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, google-apps-script, wsdl

I am using the following code to get a result but for some reason I am getting this error: **Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog. (line 134, file "Code")**    which in this case is

> var xmlResult = XmlService.parse(result).getRootElement();

```
var xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:v1=\"http://openclinica.org/ws/studySubject/v1\" xmlns:bean=\"http://openclinica.org/ws/beans\">"
       +"<soapenv:Header>"
        +"<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\">"
        +"<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id=\"UsernameToken-27777511\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">"
        +"<wsse:Username>yyyy</wsse:Username>"
        +"<wsse:Password>xxxxx</wsse:Password>"
        +"</wsse:UsernameToken>"
        +"</wsse:Security>"
       +"</soapenv:Header>"
       +"<soapenv:Body>"
          +"<v1:listAllByStudyRequest>"
             +"<bean:studyRef>"
                +"<bean:identifier>PROSPER2</bean:identifier>"
             +"</bean:studyRef>"
          +"</v1:listAllByStudyRequest>"
       +"</soapenv:Body>"
    +"</soapenv:Envelope>";


      var options =
      {
        "method" : "post",
        "contentType" : "text/xml",
        "payload" : xml
      };

      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica-ws/ws/studySubject/v1/studySubjectWsdl.wsdl", options);

      var xmlResult = XmlService.parse(result).getRootElement();


      Logger.log(xmlResult);
```

Any idea why this is not working, I am using google apps script to execute this code;

Comment: if I execute the above xml using soapUI it works fine.

Comment: What is the size of the XML returned? >10MB?

Comment: I dont think it is even 100kb @JackBrown

Comment: Can you supply a sample of xml what will be returned, `Logger.log("result")`

Comment: @JackBrown https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6808b245c630fe2eca6f234b8117b8d8

Comment: Well Xmlparse is working fine on your data, I doubt that what is being returned by UrlFetch is not an xml response. What you get when you add this after URLFetct `Logger.log(result)`. plus try this to `var xmlResult = XmlService.parse(result.getContentText()).getRootElement();`

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599919/java-parsing-xml-document-gives-content-not-allowed-in-prolog-error). Check the xml file whether it has any junk character like this �. It's also stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569123/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-saxparserexception) that this error is probably related to a byte order mark (BOM) prior to the actual XML content. You need to parse the returned String and discard the BOM, so SAXParser can process the document correctly.